Express app response 200, empty body on Render
I am making a really small app (just register and login) with Express.js.
When I reach localhost:5000/api/auth/login, it works fine, returning a token.
But the deployed version on Render returns 200 with empty body. If I try visit the site with the postfix of /api/auth/login, it will display on the site, 'Not Found'.
When the app was deployed, it printed that everything went successfully, all is set up and ready to go.
Does any one know what's the matter?
Here's my file tree:

index.js:
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/authRoutes'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

authRoutes.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { registerUser, loginUser } = require('../controllers/authController');

router.post('/register', registerUser);

router.post('/login', loginUser);

module.exports = router;

And, if needed, Github: https://github.com/atryknaav/iteamtest-server
I tried changing the link of the hosted version, like /api/auth/login => /login or /api/v1/auth/login, but the same thing.
Edited


Try adding a simple "GET" with a "hello" msg, to understand if you have a routing issue or a .env / db issue.

Prob routing issue, but idk how to fix it cause everything works fine, when I test it on localhost

Are there any logs?  If not generate some.

How do you deploy your code?  In particular is config/db sitting in a public repo or how do you get that into production?  https://docs.render.com/configure-environment-variables might be of interest.

Yeah, it's in a public repo, and when the build is complete on Render, it says 'Connected to MongoDB', and the console.log() is in the db.js file, so it does use it. The only thing I can think of for now is that some params of the ones that I added in the edited version of this post are configured in a wrong way

I don't know Render.com but that screenshot looks like something I'd expect to see for static file hosting. Notice that it says "Build Command" and not "Start Command"? I think you need to check out these docs - https://docs.render.com/deploy-node-express-app

OMG YES, I changed it to 'Web Service' and it is working now. Thank you! You helped me out so much! I have like 2-3 hours to finish my thing ahahahaha Thanks again!

Ensure that you have added the .env file to the deployment.
